# HDF file not saving properly with h5py

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to save a numpy array in a HDF file with h5py as follows:

```
with h5py.File("mfcc_aligned.hdf", "w") as aligned_f:
    # do stuff to create two numpy arrays, training_X and training_Y
    print(len(training_X)) # this returns the number of elements I expect in the the numpy arr
    aligned_f.create_dataset("train_X", data=training_X)
    aligned_f.create_dataset("train_Y", data=training_Y)
    # if I add a line here to access the datasets I just created, I see that aligned_f does indeed have two keys train_X and train_Y with the shapes I expect
```

However, when the program ends and I check the file `mfcc_aligned.hdf`, it's exactly 800 bytes (much smaller than I expect), and there are no keys. I'm at a loss for what's going on here.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: did you try:  with h5py.File('mfcc_aligned.hdf', 'r') as hf:
    print = hf['train_X'][:]

Answer (score 0):

did you try(didn't format in the comments):

```
with h5py.File('mfcc_aligned.hdf', 'r') as hf:
    print hf['train_X'][:]
```

Comment: What's that `print =` do?

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems with your code:

```
In [59]: import h5py
In [60]: training_X = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [61]: training_Y = np.arange(3).reshape(3,1)
In [62]: with h5py.File("mfcc_aligned.hdf", "w") as aligned_f:
    ...:     # do stuff to create two numpy arrays, training_X and training_Y
    ...:     print(len(training_X)) # this returns the number of elements I expe
    ...: ct in the the numpy arr
    ...:     aligned_f.create_dataset("train_X", data=training_X)
    ...:     aligned_f.create_dataset("train_Y", data=training_Y)
    ...:     
3
In [63]: f = h5py.File("mfcc_aligned.hdf")
In [64]: list(f.keys())
Out[64]: ['train_X', 'train_Y']
In [66]: f['train_X'].value
Out[66]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [67]: f['train_Y'][:]
Out[67]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
In [68]: ll mfcc_aligned.hdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 2204 Mar 31 14:10 mfcc_aligned.hdf
```